# Adding resource to androidmanifest.xml in Qt Android project

Tags: android, qt5, android-manifest

I am trying to add device filter to the androidmanifest.xml as shwn below,

```
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.extract_android_style" android:value="minimal"/>
    <!-- extract android style -->
    <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"
     android:resource="@xml/devices_filter" />
```

But when compiling Qt Creator gives the below error,

> android-build\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:173:
> error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at
> 'resource' with value '@xml/devices_filter').

I tried adding it to `OTHER_FILES`, and `DIST_FILES` but still the same issue.
Here is an excerpt from my .pri file,

> ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = $$PWD/android-$$TARGET
>
> OTHER_FILES += 
> $$ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR/AndroidManifest.xml 
> $$ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR/res/xml/device_filter.xml \
>
> DISTFILES += 
> $$ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR/AndroidManifest.xml 
> $$ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR/res/xml/device_filter.xml 
> $$ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR/build.gradle

How can I get my `res/xml/device_filter.xml` added to the project so that it can be referenced in androidmanifest?